# How to call a function(UNBOUND function) in angualrjs on window tab close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a ajax call on the controller, i need to call a function on window closed or location changed

my sample function call is :

```
$scope.func = function()
{
  //ajax code goes here
}
```

also i tried the below method

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
   if (!answer) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //ajax code goes here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same controller where the function is defined, you can attach an event listener on the `window` object:

```
window.onclose = function() {
    $scope.func  
}
```

Or you can add the `onunload` to the `body` tag:

```
<body onunload="func()">
```

Note that the app name must be in the `html` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onbeforeunload event for when people leave your page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: wooow its working fine , thanks a lot @Torben Jensen

Comment: i need another one help i need to call a ajax if user click the leave button , can u please help me